Proof of Morse Lemma
I was trying to understand the proof of Morse Lemma( Lemma 2.2) from the book  Morse Theory by J.Milnor. https://luis.impa.br/aulas/topdif/Milnor_MorseTheory.pdf
Morse Lemma : Let $p$ be a non-degenerate critical point for $ f : M$ . Then there is a local co-ordinate system $(y_1 ,...,y_n)$ in a neighbourhood of $U$ of $p$ with $ \forall i , y_i (p)=0 $ and such that the identity $ f = f(p)- (y_1)^2 - ... -(y_ {\lambda })^2 +(y_ {\lambda +1 })^2  + ...+ (y_n)^2 $ holds throughout $U$, where $ \lambda $ is the index of $ f $at $p$.
The proof of this lemma followed by the induction . I was trying to understand the inductive hypothesis . What I understand is the following :
Want to prove $ \forall r \in $ { 0 , 1, ..., n }   there exist coordinates  $ (y_1, . . . , y_n)
$ on a neighbourhood $U_r$  of $0$ such that $ f(y_1, . . . , y_n) = - (y_1)^2 - ... -(y_ r)^2 + \sum_{ i, j \geq r+1 }^{n} y_i y_j h_{ij}(y_1, . . . , y_n)  $ where $h_{ij}$ are smooth function .
First it was proved the base case for $r=0$ , $ f(y_1, . . . , y_n) =  \sum_{ i, j \geq 1 }^{n} y_i y_j h_{ij}(y_1, . . . , y_n)  $.
So the inductive step is :
Assume  for  $r  \in $ { 0 , 1, ..., n-1 } there exist coordinates  $ (y_1, . . . , y_n)
$ on a neighbourhood $U_r$  of $0$ such that $ f(y_1, . . . , y_n) = - (y_1)^2 - ... -(y_ r)^2 + \sum_{ i, j \geq r+1 }^{n} y_i y_j h_{ij}(y_1, . . . , y_n)  $ .
Am I right ?
